# A 'contents' key is required while uploading a file using Http client

Tags: laravel, http, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am struggling with a weird problem. I am trying to upload a file to a different server using the API. I am using Laravel 8.X and Using HTTP client for the same. Below is my code which I am calling from a controller

```php
if ($request->hasFile('uploadReceipt') && $request->file('uploadReceipt')->isValid()) { 
    $receiptContent = file_get_contents($request->file('uploadReceipt'));
    $originalName = $request->file('uploadReceipt')->getClientOriginalName();
    $responseUploadReceipt = Http::attach('attachment', $receiptContent, $originalName)
        ->withHeaders([
            'Accept'=> 'application/json', 
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$userAccessToken 
        ])
        ->post($endpoint, $requestData); 

    dd($responseUploadReceipt->json()); 
} else { 
    dd ("Else"); 
}
```

I am getting A 'contents' key is required, in the file `vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/MultipartStream.php:86`
I spent almost 12 hrs on it but unable to resolve this issue. I also tried with the stream like

```php
$receiptContent = fopen($request->file('uploadReceipt'), 'r');
```

but the same issue. I followed the same way it is mentioned in the documentation. Anyone who can help me with this will be appreciated.

Thanks and Regards
Ashish

Answer (score 0):

You were probably using **multipart**  in conjunction with  **form_params** , this is not explicitly explained in the documentation of laravel but guzzle won't work with both

> Note
>
> multipart cannot be used with the form_params option. You will need to
> use one or the other. Use form_params for
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded requests, and multipart for
> multipart/form-data requests.
>
> This option cannot be used with body, form_params, or json

To solve this problem you will need to parse all the params to multipart, if you are using laravel or lumen you can do it in this way

```
 if(!empty($this->files))
                {

                 //if there is an image parse all the rest parameters to 
                  multipart

                  $file_keys=array_keys($this->files);

                  foreach($this->files as $k => $file)
                  {
                  $http = $http->attach($k, file_get_contents($file),$k);
                  }

                  foreach($this->data as $dk =>&$d)
                  {
                     if(!in_array($dk,$file_keys))
                     {
                        if(is_array($d))
                        {
                           $d=json_encode($d);
                        }

                        $http = $http->attach($dk,$d);
  
                     }

                  }

                //if there isn't any file just send all as form_params
                  return $http=$http->post($this->url);
 
                }
               return $http=$http->post($this->url,$this->data);
```

https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#multipart

Answer (score -2):

I think this line is the problem:

```
$receiptContent = file_get_contents($request->file('uploadReceipt'));
```

The examples in the documentation do not use the `Request`. `$request->file('uploadReceipt')` should return an instance of `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` and I'm pretty sure `file_get_contents` doesn't work with an `UploadedFile` as a parameter.

Digging deeper into the class file, it seems there is a method to get the `UploadedFile`'s contents:

> `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`
>
> ```php
>     /**
>      * Get the contents of the uploaded file.
>      *
>      * @return false|string
>      *
>      * @throws \Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException
>      */
>     public function get()
>     {
>         if (! $this->isValid()) {
>             throw new FileNotFoundException("File does not exist at path {$this->getPathname()}.");
>         }
>
>         return file_get_contents($this->getPathname());
>     }
> ```

Try `$receiptContent = $request->file('uploadReceipt')->get();` instead.